# iTunes 11 reverts to season 1 of a show after watching an episode

Tags: itunes

Since upgrading to iTunes 11 with it's wonderful interface I've run into an issue. I have several TV shows with multiple seasons. It's great that the interface now groups the seasons all into one icon for the show. However, if I select a later season (eg. 2) and watch an episode, when it finishes and iTunes goes back to it's window, I'm back on Season 1.

Quite an irritation to have to scroll back up to the top of the show, go back to the season I'm watching, and then scroll back down to find the episode I was on.

Is this just a bug, or am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug that was fixed in 11.0.1 today.